# Can not open IDLE (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, window, python-idle

I use Window 10. Before installing python 2.7, I uninstalled python 3.2. But batch file of IDLE is not opened. To solvong this problem, I tried to find  file(not finded) and write C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib>python idle.py at command prompt(there is error message, unicodedecoederror: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 0: invlid start byte'), but i can't solve the problem. What should I do?

Comment: Sidenote: You did not have to uninstall 3.2 (though I would upgrade to at least 3.5, or soon 3.6.).  `py -2` and `py -3` would start the respective binaries regardless of the current directory.  `py -2 -m idlelib.idle` should start IDLE.  (With 3.x, `-m idlelib` is sufficient`.  To make sure that `python` is linked to 2.7, enter that alone and see how the interactive interpreter identifies itself.  Since for me, `python` is 3.5, I entered `...\idlelib>py -2 idle.py` and IDLE starts fine.

Comment: All the files in idlelib, including idle.py, only have ascii text.  So byte 0xb1 cannot be in any of them unless the file is corrupted.  Please copy and paste the *entire* traceback, and mark it as 'code' by selecting it and hitting the `{}` markup button.  Perhaps it will give a clue as to the problem on your system.